# Resampling two vectors with interp1 or spline

Tags: arrays, matlab, spline, resampling

**Situation**:

I was trying to compare two signal vectors (y1 & y2 with time vectors x1 & x2) with different lengths (len(y1)=1000>len(y2)=800). For this, I followed the main piece of advice given hardly everywhere: to use interp1 or spline. In order to 'expand' y2 towards y1 in number of samples through an interpolation. 
So I want:

```
length(y1)=length(y2_interp)
```

However, in these functions you have to give the points 'x' where to interpolate (xq), so I generate a vector with the resampled points I want to compute:

```
xq = x2(1):(length(x2))/length(x1):x2(length(x2));
y2_interp = interp1(x2,y2,xq,'spline'); % or spline method directly

RMS = rms(y1-y2_interp)
```

**The problem:**

When I resample the x vector in 'xq' variable, *as the faction of lengths is not an integer* it gives me not the same length for 'y2_interp' as 'y1'. I cannot round it for the same problem.

I tried interpolate using the 'resample' function:

```
 y2_interp=resample(y2,length(y1),length(y2),n);
```

But I get an aliasing problem and I want to avoid filters if possible. And if n=0 (no filters) I get some sampling problems and more RMS.

The two vectors are quite long, so my misalignment is just of 2 or 3 points.

**What I'm looking for:**

*I would like to find a way of interpolating one vector but having as a reference the length of another one, and not the points where I want to interpolate.*

I hope I have explained it well... Maybe I have some misconception. It's more than i'm curious about any possible idea.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for here is [`linspace`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html)

To get an evenly spaced vector `xq` with the same endpoints as `x2` but the same length as `x1`:

`xq = (x2(1),x2(end),length(x1));`

Comment: This gives the right number of points, but will still not compute `RMS` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is not sufficient to interpolate `y2` to get the right number of samples, the samples should be at locations corresponding to samples of `y1`.

Thus, you want to interpolate `y2` at the x-coordinates where you have samples for `y1`, which is given by `x1`:

```
y2_interp = interp1(x2,y2,x1,'spline'); 
RMS = rms(y1-y2_interp)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my late response. I tried this solution but is it possible it gives me a huge divergence along the x1 vector when I carry out extrapolation instead of interpolation with "interp1" function?

Comment: Yes, don't ever extrapolate. Compare the two signals only in the domain where they are both defined.